# Using scanner of Canon Pixma MG3052 with sane

Tags: canon, scanner, mint, sane

I have bought this week a Canon Pixma MG3052, which is a multifunction printer. I installed the printer drivers from canon's website and "Scan Gear MP".

I am able to scan with the `scangearmp2` command, but I am unable to do the same with `scanimage`. The scanner is not found, and if I add it manually to the `/etc/sane.d/pixma.conf`, an error shows up:

```
[bjnp] udp_command: ERROR - no data received (timeout = 1000)
[bjnp] bjnp_init_device_structure: Cannot read mac address, skipping this scanner
[bjnp] udp_command: ERROR - no data received (timeout = 1000)
[bjnp] add_scanner: ERROR - Cannot read scanner make & model: bjnp://192.168.1.2
```

I have upgraded my sane version using `sane-git` with no success, the same message keeps happening.

I've read the sane-pixma man page and the MG3000 series does not seem to be supported.

After a lot of research, I've seen that the underlying protocol that sane-pixma uses is BJNP on port 8612. I've then come across this page : 
http://www.qwhatis.com/what-is-bjnp/

> The BJNP protocol is part of the older Canon Pixma printer models.

and

> People have always complained about the printing limitations under the BJNP protocol

If I understand well, the new printer I've bought does not use BJNP anymore and I can't use the sane-pixma backend to scan? How do I do then?

Does anyone knows what is the new protocol to use?

Comment: The [SANE supported devices list](http://www.sane-project.org/lists/sane-mfgs-cvs.html#Z-CANON) says "testers needed" for the Pixma MG3000 series, so you may want to get in touch with the SANE developers.

Comment: By the way, I see this question is tagged "mint"; if you are using Linux Mint, then this is off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try to get in touch with them.
I tagged it "mint", but I dont think this issue is mint-specific, because the packages I am using are from ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Not Mint specific for sure but AskUbuntu supports Ubuntu and official derivatives only.

Comment: There is a program called `scangearmp2` you can get from the Canon website for Linux, which uses `libusb` (so it is not a kernel driver). I just got a MG3051 - and one of the stupidest things I have seen on it yet, is that if the Alert orange light is flashing because you don't have any print cartridges installed (I don't want to install them, because I don't intend to print - just scan), then it will not let you scan with "`The printer is in operation. Check the printer. Scanner driver will be closed.`" Ugh!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Pixma MG3051/MG3052 does not support the BJNP protocol. The port 8612 used by BJNP appears closed. I think it might work with the sane-pixma driver if connected by USB cable, but I don't think there is support for scanning over network with sane.

Indeed Canon's own scangearmp2 works over network if you use version 3.40 or newer. I took a capture and the protocol seems quite simple http-based one, called CHMP (Canon HTTP Management Protocol). In case anyone is interested, the capture is [here](https://jpa.kapsi.fi/stuff/other/canon-pixma-mg3051-scanning-with-scangearmp2-3.40.txt).

Answer (score 0):

For scanner, have you tried sane-escl (inside sane-backends) or sane-airscan (https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan)? I tried it with my Canon TS9020 and they both work.